# How to count json nodes in postgres jsonb

Tags: postgresql

In my Postgres database I have a column jsonb with a order items:

```
[
{"discount": 29.96, "quantity": 1, "item_value": 69.94, "unit_price": 99.9, "stock_sku_id": 98906, "product_sku_id": 98775}, 
{"discount": 52.81, "quantity": 1, "item_value": 123.19, "unit_price": 176.0, "stock_sku_id": 15183, "product_sku_id": 15077}
]
```

I need count number of lines in this order.

I tried to use:

```
select (o.data->'items') from orders o where o.id = 34505

select count((o.data->'items')) from orders o where o.id = 34505

select (o.data->'items').count() from orders o where o.id = 34505
```

But any solution works.

Answer (score 0):

I solve using JSONB_ARRAY_LENGTH function!